# Backbone.js on event's callback function

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I am trying to understand Backbone.js and I have a question related to the below example -

```
var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({
  promptColor: function() {
    var cssColor = prompt("Please enter a CSS color:");
    this.set({color: cssColor});
  }
});

window.sidebar = new Sidebar;

sidebar.on('change:color', function(model, color) {
  $('#sidebar').css({background: color});
});

sidebar.set({color: 'white'});

sidebar.promptColor();
```

The on event has the syntax - onobject.on(event, callback, [context]). In the above example in the callback function why are we passing model variable ?

Thanks,
prat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Backbone [model.change event](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) passes 3 callback arguments that you can (optionally) use:

```
model.on("change:[attribute]", function(model, value, options), [context]);
```

Your code uses the first 2 of these. When color changes, the callback gets the model that changed and the new color:

```
sidebar.on('change:color', function(model, color) {        
    $('#sidebar').css({background: color});
});
```

This can also accomplished by setting the model as the callback's `this` context:

```
sidebar.on('change:color', function() {
    $('#sidebar').css({background: this.get('color')});
}, sidebar);
```

See both examples in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/b7y3W/2/